# Training on the full dataset after cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-selection

**TL:DR**: Is it ever a good idea to train an ML model on all the data available before shipping it to production? Put another way, is it ever ok to train on all data available and **not** check if the model overfits, or get a final read of the expected performance of the model?

---

Say I have a **family of models** parametrized by $\alpha$. I can do a search (e.g. a grid search) on $\alpha$ by, for example, running k-fold cross-validation for each candidate.

The point of using cross-validation for choosing $\alpha$ is that I can check if ***a*** learned model $\beta_i$ for **that** particular $\alpha_i$ had e.g. overfit, by testing it on the "unseen data" in each CV iteration (a validation set). After iterating through all $\alpha_i$'s, I could then choose a model $\beta_{\alpha^*}$ learned for the parameters $\alpha^*$ that seemed to do best on the grid search, e.g. on average across all folds.

Now, say that **after model selection** I would like to use **all** the the data that I have available in an attempt to ship the best possible model in production.  For this, I could use the parameters $\alpha^*$ that I chose via grid search with cross-validation, and then, after training the model on the full ($F$) dataset, I would a get a single **new** learned model $\beta^{F}_{\alpha^*}$

The problem is that, if I use my entire dataset for training,  **I can't reliably check if this new learned model** $\beta^{F}_{\alpha^*}$ **overfits** or how it may perform on unseen data. So is this at all good practice? What is a good way to think about this problem?

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52274 with lots of worthy answers. Perhaps these threads should be merged but I am not sure in which direction. Both have accepted answers that are very good.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The way to think of cross-validation is as estimating the performance obtained using a method for building a model, rather than for estimating the performance of a model.

If you use cross-validation to estimate the hyperparameters of a model (the $\alpha$s) and then use those hyper-parameters to fit a model to the whole dataset, then that is fine, provided that you recognise that the cross-validation estimate of performance is likely to be (possibly substantially) optimistically biased.  This is because part of the model (the hyper-parameters) have been selected to minimise the cross-validation performance, so if the cross-validation statistic has a non-zero variance (and it will) there is the possibility of over-fitting the model selection criterion.

If you want to choose the hyper-parameters and estimate the performance of the resulting model then you need to perform a nested cross-validation, where the outer cross-validation is used to assess the performance of the model, and in each fold cross-validation is used to determine the hyper-parameters separately in each fold.  You build the final model by using cross-validation on the whole set to choose the hyper-parameters and then build the classifier on the whole dataset using the optimized hyper-parameters.

This is of course computationally expensive, but worth it as the bias introduced by improper performance estimation can be large.  See my paper

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 2010. Research, vol. 11, pp. 2079-2107, July 2010. ([www](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v11/cawley10a.html), [pdf](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf))

However, it is still possible to have over-fitting in model selection (nested cross-validation just allows you to test for it).  A method I have found useful is to add a regularisation term to the cross-validation error that penalises hyper-parameter values likely to result in overly-complex models, see

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Preventing over-fitting in model selection via Bayesian regularisation of the hyper-parameters, Journal of Machine Learning Research, volume 8, pages 841-861, April 2007. ([www](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v8/cawley07a.html),[pdf](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume8/cawley07a/cawley07a.pdf))

So the answers to your question are (i) yes, you should use the full dataset to produce your final model as the more data you use the more likely it is to generalise well but (ii) make sure you obtain an unbiased performance estimate via nested cross-validation and potentially consider penalising the cross-validation statistic to further avoid over-fitting in model selection.

Comment: +1: Answers the question: "If you use cross-validation to estimate the hyperparameters of a model (the αs) and then use those hyper-parameters to fit a model to the whole dataset, then that is fine…"

Comment: What could be a different approach from a nested cross-validation? Can we run some initial experiments and observe a proper setting for the hyper-parameter and then use cross-validation for the parameters?

Comment: @soufanom, no, the use of "initial experiments" to make choices regarding the model is likely to result in over-fitting and almost certainly will introduce an optimistic bias into the performance analysis.  The cross-validation used for performance analysis must repeat EVERY step used in fitting the model independently in each fold.  The experiments in my paper show that kernel models can be very sensitive to this sort of bias, so it is vital to perform the model selection and performance evaluation with all possible rigour.

Comment: Thanks for your direct response. I want to avoid nested-cross validation because of its high computational time cost. Lets say I have an alpha and lambda parameters. Can I loop over values of alpha and within every value we apply cross-validation for lambda? This might still more optimistic than the nested-cross validation but is it acceptable?

Comment: For kernel methods, such as the SVM, it is often possible to perform leave-one-out cross-validation at almost no computational cost (see the papers listed in my answer).  I use this "virtual" leave-one-out cross-validation for tuning the hyper-parameters, nested in k-fold cross-validation for performance evaluation.  The cost is then quite reasonable.  In my opinion it is not acceptable to use any procedure where the performance evaluation is biased in any way by the tuning of the hyper-parameters.  It is worth the computational expense to get a reliable estimate.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial. I don't quite get the third paragraph in your answer. If I do nested cross-validation, I will get a different set of hyperparameters for each fold of the **outer** CV (i.e. I get one set of hyperparameters from running the **inner** CV on a grid of parameters). How do I then choose the best set of hyperparameters?

Comment: cross-validation is essentially a means of estimating the performance of a *method* of fitting a model, rather than of the method itself.  So after performing nested cross-validation to get the performance estimate, just rebuild the final model using the entire dataset, using the procedure that you have cross-validated (which includes the selection of the hyper-parameters).

Comment: This is a very good answer (+1). I have been reviewing your answers on this topic and looked in your 2010 Cawley&Talbot paper too, because I came across a simple situation where I get exactly the same error estimate whether I do nested cross-validation or not. This made me wonder what are the situations in which nested CV would make a difference. I asked this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178174, and would be very interested in your input! Thank you.

Comment: So, if we use nested cross validation, after performing it, we can build the final model on the whole dataset using the optimized hyper-parameters. But if the we use hold out to assess model performance and cross validation on the training set to tune the parameters, we can't. Why is that? I don't understand. Please see this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153366/question-about-training-set-and-test-set. Thank you

Comment: I don't think I mention hold-out in my answer. but it depends on how cross-validation and hold-out are used.  If you cross-validate on all of the available data and then split the data into training and test sets and use the cross-validated hyper-parameters, that would give an optimistically biased performance estimate.  However, there is no reason why you shouldn't retrain on all of the available data.  The point is that cross-validation is an estimate of the performance of a method of generating a model, rather than of the model itself.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Thank you for this answer. In the comments above, you wrote: "after performing nested cross-validation to get the performance estimate, just rebuild the final model using the entire dataset, using the procedure that you have cross-validated." Just to be clear - you should only report the performance estimate from nested CV for the final model - right?

Comment: @BerkU. yes, that is what I would do.

Comment: This answer must be emphasized. People are usually clueless about what to do after nested cross-validation,

Comment: @DikranMarsupial: say I use nested CV to evaluate a modeling process that includes a search for some hyperP lambda in range(3,4). I get avg error over folds of 0.2 (unacceptable for application).  I redo the nested CV, but this time I search for lambda in range(1,6). I get error 0.01.  If I choose the second modeling process, I feel I'll fall victim to optimism mentioned in your paper.  How are we supposed to find search spaces, though, if not by this method..? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282954/does-changing-the-parameter-search-space-after-nested-cv-introduce-optimistic-bi

Comment: Philosophically, why do you use a pseudonym, and post a paper of yours from which your true name can be inferred? (BTW: great answer, thank you, also for the link to the book)

Answer (score 27):

Just to add to the answer by @mark999, Max Kuhn's [`caret`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) package (Classification and Regression Training) is the most comprehensive source in R for model selection based on bootstrap cross validation or N-fold CV and some other schemes as well.

Not to disregard the greatness of the `rms` package, but `caret` lets you fit pretty much every learning method available in R, whereas `validate` only works with `rms` methods (I think).

The `caret` package is a single infrastructure to pre process data, fit and evaluate any popular model, hence it is simple to use for all methods and provides graphical assessment of many performance measures (something that next to the overfit problem might influence the model selection considerably as well) over your grid and variable importance.

See the package vignettes to get started (it is very simple to use)
[Data Preprocessing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretMisc.pdf)
[Variable Selection with caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretSelection.pdf)
[Model Building with caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretTrain.pdf)
[Variable Importance](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretVarImp.pdf)

You may also view the caret website for more information on the package, and specific implementation examples:
[Offical caret website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if, after model selection (which is done by calling `train`), there is a way in caret to train with the full dataset?

Comment: Not sure if that is a good idea or why you would want to that, but you can just fit the final model returned by train to the full data set.

Answer (score 19):

I believe that Frank Harrell would recommend bootstrap validation rather than cross validation. Bootstrap validation would allow you to validate the model fitted on the full data set, and is more stable than cross validation. You can do it in R using `validate` in Harrell's `rms` package.

See the book "Regression Modeling Strategies" by Harrell and/or "An Introduction to the Bootstrap" by Efron and Tibshirani for more information.

Comment: To omit a next myth about "bad CV", this is a terminology problem -- Harrell's "cross validation" means N-fold CV, and "bootstrap validation" means resampling CV. Obviously I agree that this second flavor is more stable and overall nicer, but this is also a type of cross validation.

Comment: mark999 or @mbq, would you mind elaborating on how bootstrap would allow one to validate a model fitted on the full dataset?

Comment: @user27915816 Well, in principle nohow; the idea behind cross-validation is that you tests whether given *training method* is reliably making good models on a sets very similar to the final one, and, if so, generalise this observation to the full set with a silent assumptions that nothing strange will happen and that CV method you used is not somehow biased. This is of course almost always good enough, still you can never be *sure* that the model built on all the data you have is not overfitted.

Answer (score 18):

I think you have a bunch of different questions here:

> The problem is that, if I use all points in my dataset for training, I can't check if this new learned model βfull overfits!

The thing is, you can use (one) validation step only for one thing: either for parameter optimization, (x)or for estimating generalization performance.

So, if you do parameter optimization by cross validation (or any other kind of data-driven parameter determination), you need test samples that are independent of those training and optimization samples. Dikran calls it nested cross validation, another name is double cross validation. Or, of course, an independent test set.

> So here's the question for this post : Is it a good idea to train with the full dataset after k-fold cross-validation? 
>   Or is it better instead to stick with one of the models learned in one of the cross-validation splits for αbest?

Using one of the cross validation models usually is *worse* than training on the full set (at least if your learning curve performance = f (nsamples) is still increasing. In practice, it is: if it wasn't, you would probably have set aside an independent test set.)

If you observe a large variation between the cross validation models (with the same parameters), then your models are unstable. In that case, aggregating the models can help and actually be better than using the *one* model trained on the whole data.

*Update:* This aggregation is the idea behind [bagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) applied to resampling without replacement (cross validation) instead of to resampling with replacement (bootstrap / out-of-bootstrap validation).

Here's a paper where we used this technique:
[Beleites, C. & Salzer, R.: Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations, Anal Bioanal Chem, 390, 1261-1271 (2008).

DOI: 10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6)

> Perhaps most importantly, how can I train with all points in my dataset and still fight overfitting?

By being very conservative with the degrees of freedom allowed for the "best" model, i.e. by taking into account the (random) uncertainty on the optimization cross validation results. If the d.f. are actually appropriate for the cross validation models, chances are good that they are not too many for the *larger* training set.
The pitfall is that parameter optimization is actually multiple testing. You need to guard against accidentally good looking parameter sets.

Comment: `...If you observe a large variation between the cross validation models (with the same parameters), then your models are unstable. In that case, aggregating the models can help...` Can you explain this a bit more? e.g. if I am running logistic regression in a 10-k cross validated setup and end up with 10 sets of coefficients, do you recommend aggregating the coeff estimates to form a final model? If so, how can this be done, just taking the means?

Comment: @cbeleites can you elaborate on `If the d.f. are actually appropriate for the cross validation models`. In my understanding you are arguing that the train/validation sets are not very large when compared with the complete data set, am I right?

Comment: @Zhubarb Are you referring to 10x k-folds (5 for instance)? If so, I believe the best practice would be to use the model with best model selection parameters that comes out of each of the 10x k-folds. For each k-fold you get an average RMSE or R2 in the case of regression so you get already a kind of aggregated model. But care should be paid in the presence of unstable models. Perhaps the "best" model is not the one that comes from CV but the second or third, depending on the train/test data sets. Difficult to know without trying I think.

Comment: See `http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/cv-final.pdf`

Comment: @Zhubarb: aggregation is AFAIK more usually done with the predictions. For linear models, the results are the same if you average coefficients or predictions, but already for LR, the results will be different because of the nonlinear transformation. Please see the paper in the text for more details and an example.

Comment: @jpcgandre: Choosing one of the surrogate models for further use is in fact a data-driven model selection, which means that you need an outer independent level of validation. And in general, unless you have enough cases so you can actually do statistically meaningful model comparisons on the basis of testing $\frac{1}{k}$ of the total sample size, IMHO you should not select.

Comment: More importantly: the iterated cross validation surrogate models share the same set of hyperparameters. That is, they are equivalent in all you deem to be important but the arbitrary selection of training and test cases. Selecting a "good" model thus in fact should primarily select a good test/training set combination - which is fundamentally what we usually do *not* want: we want a choice that is generalizing well and thus not only working for favorable cases. From this point of view, selecting a surrogate model from a "normal" cross validation does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @jpcgandre: (d.f.) I argue that choosing a model complexity that is appropriate for training on $1 - \frac{1}{k}$ of the data set (which I argue is almost as large as the whole data set), you may arrive at a bias towards slightly too restrictive models for training on the whole data set. However, I don't think this should matter in practice, the more so as my impression in my field is that we rather tend to err towards too complex models.

Answer (score 6):

What you do is not a cross validation, rather some kind of stochastic optimization.

The idea of CV is to simulate a performance on unseen data by performing several rounds of building the model on a subset of objects and testing on the remaining ones. The somewhat averaged results of all rounds are the **approximation of  performance of a model trained on the whole set**.

In your case of model selection, you should perform a full CV for each parameter set, and thus get a on-full-set performance approximation for each setup, so seemingly the thing you wanted to have.

However, note that it is not at all guaranteed that the model with best approximated accuracy will be the best in fact -- you may cross-validate the whole model selection procedure to see that there exist some range in parameter space for which the differences in model accuracies are not significant.

Comment: Thanks @mbq, but I'm not sure I follow. I **do** N-fold cross-validation for each point value of my grid search in the  hyperparameter space. The average result of the N-folds gives me the approximation that you mention, which I use to compare models and do model selection by selecting the model the best fits the validation set. 

My question is about what happens when I train with the full dataset. I think the learned model changes (the $\vec\beta$ parameters of the learned model change), and in principle I have no way to know if I suffer from overfitting.

Comment: @AmV If so, ok -- as I wrote, CV already tests full set scenario, you cannot say more without new data. Again, you can at most do a nested CV to see  if there is no overfitting imposed by the model selection itself (if the selection gives very good improvement or the data is noisy the risk of this is quite big).

Answer (score 0):

I found Moiser 1951, https://doi.org/10.1177/001316445101100101 claim:

1. obtain performance metrics using cross-validation
2. use the whole dataset to build a final, more accurate model

His last words are:

> Possibly one of the other speakers knows a proof that the [coefficient of determination] R of the half sample's beta is always lower than of the full sample beta [where beta is the coefficients of a model]

Does somebody have a proof by now (in the year 2023)?

Comment: I posted this follow up question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/622128/298651