# Choice of K in K-fold cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I've been using the $K$-fold cross-validation a few times now to evaluate performance of some learning algorithms, but I've always been puzzled as to how I should choose the value of $K$.

I've often seen and used a value of $K = 10$, but this seems totally arbitrary to me, and I now just use $10$ by habit instead of thinking it over. To me it seems that you're getting a better granularity as you improve the value of $K$, so ideally you should make your $K$ very large, but there is also a risk to be biased.

I'd like to know what the value of $K$ should depend on, and how I should be thinking about this when I evaluate my algorithm. Does it change something if I use the *stratified* version of the cross-validation or not?

Comment: A very related newer thread: [Optimal number of folds in K-fold cross-validation: is leave-one-out CV the best choice?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61546/)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The choice of $k = 10$ is somewhat arbitrary. Here's how I decide $k$:

- first of all, in order to lower the variance of the CV result, you can and should repeat/iterate the CV with new random splits. 
   This makes the argument of high $k$ => more computation time largely irrelevant, as you anyways want to calculate many models. I tend to think mainly of the total number of models calculated (in analogy to bootstrapping). So I may decide for 100 x 10-fold CV or 200 x 5-fold CV.
- @ogrisel already explained that usually large $k$ mean less (pessimistic) bias. (Some exceptions are known particularly for $k = n$, i.e. leave-one-out).
- If possible, I use a $k$ that is a divisor of the sample size, or the size of the groups in the sample that should be stratified.
- Too large $k$ mean that only a low number of sample combinations is possible, thus limiting the number of iterations that are different.

  - For leave-one-out: $\binom{n}{1} = n = k$ different model/test sample combinations are possible. Iterations don't make sense at all.
  - E.g. $n = 20$ and $k = 10$: $\binom{n=20}{2} = 190 = 19 ⋅ k$ different model/test sample combinations exist. You may consider going through all possible combinations here as 19 iterations of $k$-fold CV or a total of 190 models is not very much.
- These thoughts have more weight with small sample sizes. With more samples available $k$ doesn't matter very much. The possible number of combinations soon becomes large enough so the (say) 100 iterations of 10-fold CV do not run a great risk of being duplicates. Also, more training samples usually means that you are at a flatter part of the learning curve, so the difference between the surrogate models and the "real" model trained on all $n$ samples becomes negligible.

Comment: (+1) for the elaboration, but (-1) for the repetition counts of the CV. It is true, that the risk of creating **exact** duplicats (looking at the ids of the observations) is small (given enough data etc.), but the risk of creating **pattern/ data structure** duplicates is very high. I would not repeat a CV more than 10 times, no matter what k is ... just to avoid underestimation of the variance.

Comment: @steffen, isn't that what ogrisel already pointed out: that the (surrogate) models are not really independent? I completely agree that this is the case. Actually, I try to take this into account by interpreting the results in terms of stability of the (surrogate) models wrt. exchanging "a few" samples (which I didn't want to elaborate here - but see e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26548/4598). And I do **not** calculate standard error but rather report e.g. median and $5^{th}$ to $95^{th}$ percentile of the observed errors over the iterations. I'll post a separate question about that.

Comment: I see. I agree that the approach is valid to estimate the stability of the surrogate. What I had back in mind was the follow-up-statistical test to decide whether one model outperforms another one. Repeating a cv way too often increases the chance of an alpha error unpredictably. So I was confusing the inner with the outer validation (as dikran has put it [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26535/264)).

Comment: @steffen, looking into such model comparisons is next on my list of things that I'd really like to look into. I personally have a lot of doubts about these data-driven optimizations. I've experienced extreme overfitting in the inner CV in some situations - and while I think the outer CV gives a sensible estimate of the resulting model's performance. For the moment I came to the conclusion that I get about as good models by deciding model parameters by my knowledge on the subject and my general experience with the models.

Comment: @cbeleites: 
Isn't it preferable to have bias and low variance than low bias and high variance? If so, then for small datasets maybe repeating a large number of times a small k (5) cross validation is best

Comment: @jpcgandre: I'd say it is preferrable to have low total error. Keep in mind that the variance reduction by iterations is limited to variance that is caused by model instability, and that there's no way to get around the fact that with whatever number of folds, in the end you only have $n$ independent cases. Assuming you do enough iterations, the variance is IMHO practically independent of the number of folds (I tend to compare same total number of surrogate models e.g. 100x 10-fold vs. 200x5-fold), but rather dominated by variance due to the available sample size.

Comment: @cbeleites: I agree with you. Variance due to limited sample size usually dominates over model uncertainty.

Comment: @ceibeles: However, the statistical uncertainty due to limited sample size is in practice unknown and hard do reduce and one usually focuses in sources more amenable such as model uncertainties. In this context, for small samples and  for the same appropriate i number (i x k-folds) if extreme values are present in the data (but which should not discarded as a pre-condition in this case) it may be preferable to choose a k value smaller than 10.

Comment: Also, returning to my original point `http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf` say that: `while unbiasedness
is reassuring, as
it means that the form of the model selection criterion is correct
on average
, the variance of the
criterion is also vitally important as it is this that ensures that the minimum of the selec
tion criterion
evaluated on a particular sample will provide good generalisation.`

Comment: @jpcgandre: At least for classification errors such as sensitivity, specificity etc., uncertainty due to total number of tested cases can be calculated. While it is true that this is only part of the total variance, at least in the situations I encounter in my work, this uncertainty is often so large that even a rough guesstimate is enough to make clear that conclusions are severely limited. And this limitation stays, it won't go away by using 50x 8-folds or 80x 5-folds instead of 40x 10-fold cross validation.

Comment: I'd say that if we think 80x 5-fold vs. 40x 10-fold could make a serious difference, then we're not in a situation where we should do any grid search optimization (as discussed in the Cawley paper): too few cases anyways. And yes, this is because of the large variance - but variance due to a source we cannot tackle by our cross validation/out of bootstrap setup.

Comment: @jpcgandre: (other $k$) sure - why not: that's part of what I mean with $k$ being a somewhat arbitrary choice.

Comment: Why you say "usually large $k$ mean less (pessimistic) bias. (Some exceptions are known particularly for $k=n$, i.e. leave-one-out)."? There are many posts that discuss why leave one out has lower bias. For exanple, [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178388/high-variance-of-leave-one-out-cross-validation#comment337904_178421) says "low bias is given because the training set is very large - almost identical with the entire dataset (as only one data sample is left out for testing). So, for one particular dataset we can expect a very good estimation."

Comment: @Maha, here's a textbook example: consider a very simple binary classifier that always predicts the majority class of its training data, and a balanced (relative frequencies 1 : 1) data set. Now, with k-fold, it is possible to set up stratified resampling, i.e. the surrogate training and test sets preserve the 1 :  1 relative frequencies. This is not possible with LOO, the left-out case will always belong to the minority class in the surrogate training set, and in consequence, it will estimate accuracy to be 0 - the worst pessimistic bias possible. k-fold CV without stratification will also...

Comment: ... have surprisingly large pessimistic bias, but (randomly) not all of the train/test splits will have the problem, so it is less pessimistic. Note that LOO is mostly preferred over k-fold with extremely small sample sizes, where this problem is more pronounced. So for k -> n the *part* of the pessimistic bias that is due to the surrogate training sets being systematically smaller than the whole data set decreases - but this is only one of the reasons that can lead to pessimistic bias.

Answer (score 46):

Larger K means less bias towards overestimating the true expected error (as training folds will be closer to the total dataset) but higher variance and higher running time (as you are getting closer to the limit case: Leave-One-Out CV).

If the slope of the learning curve is flat enough at training_size = 90% of total dataset, then the bias can be ignored and K=10 is reasonable.

Also higher K give you more samples to estimate a more accurate confidence interval on you estimate (using either parametric standard error assuming normality of the distribution of the CV test errors or non parametric bootstrap CI that just make the i.i.d assumption which is actually not very true as CV folds are not independent from one another).

Edit: underestimating => overestimating the true expected error

Edit: the part of this reply about higher variances for large K or LOOCV is probably wrong (not always true). More details with simulations in this answer: [Bias and variance in leave-one-out vs K-fold cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61783/bias-and-variance-in-leave-one-out-vs-k-fold-cross-validation/357749#357749) (thanks Xavier Bourret Sicotte for this work).

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the higher variance with large $k$? As a first approximation I'd have said that the total variance of CV result (= some kind of error calculated from all $n$ samples tested by any of the $k$ surrogate models) = variance due to testing $n$ samples only + variance due to differences between the $k$ models (instability). What am I missing?

Comment: By variance I mean variance of the estimated expected test error obtained by taking the median or mean of the CV fold errors w.r.t. the "true distribution", not across CV folds.

When k is big your are closer to LOO-CV which is very dependent on the particular training set you have at hand: if the number of samples is small it can be not so representative of the true distribution hence the variance. When k is big, k-fold CV can simulate such arbitrary hard samples of the training set.

Comment: As an addition: Kohavi studies the bias-variance-tradeoff in validation in chapter 3 of his [Phd thesis](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~ronnyk/teza.pdf). I highly recommend it.

Comment: +1, btw "larger K means higher variance", as I understand it, with large $K$, all the $K$ training sets will have large data in common, so the trained $K$ models will be somewhat correlated, resulting in **$K$ correlated test errors**, so the mean of the test error will have higher variance, right?

Comment: Yes I think this is a correct intuition.

Comment: Ideally, the K models are not only *highly* correlated, they shoud be *equal*: they are assumed to be (approximately) *equal* to the model trained on the whole data set. What remains is variance due to finite set of cases used for testing and due to training using *this particular* set of cases from the population. Wheter the latter enters the uncertainty of the result will depend on the question: it is important for "what performance can be achieved training on n such cases with that algorithm" but not for "when I use this model trained on this data, what performance can I expect".

Comment: ... so in that sense the "higher variance" means that you cannot expect the uncertainty of the mean (i.e. end result) to get lower with *k* (or repetitions/iterations). More precisely, iterations can only lower the variance between the surrogate models (= instability) to the total variance. Which is small to neglible if the models are stable.

Comment: It seems like there's a fundamental misunderstanding here on the second most upvoted answer... larger k = smaller training datasets. I would comment on the answer directly but I don't have permission. In contrast to ogrisel's answer, with higher k, training folds will be *less* similar to the total dataset. See Tibshirani & Hastie, An Introduction to Statistical Learning, pg. 181. Or the wiki on cross-validation...

Comment: @digits This is incorrect. If k equals the number of examples in the dataset, k-fold CV becomes leave-one-out CV, so the training datasets in each fold will be nearly identical to the full dataset (but less one sample).

Comment: Both Wikipedia & ISL define $k$-fold cross-validation as fitting a model on the aggregate of $k-1$ folds & testing it on the remaining fold, $k$ times.

Comment: @ogrisel I would be keen to have your views on this answer and simulation https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61783/bias-and-variance-in-leave-one-out-vs-k-fold-cross-validation/357749#357749

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `K` affects accuracy and generalization, and this may depend on the learning algorithm, but it definitely affects the computational complexity almost linearly (asymptotically, linearly) for training algorithms with algorithmic complexity linear in the number of training instances. The computational time for training increases `K-1` times if the training time is linear in the number of training instances. So for small training sets I'd consider the accuracy and generalization aspects, especially given that we need to get the most out of a limited number of training instances.

However, for large training sets and learning algorithms with high asymptotical comutational complexity growth in the number of training instances (at least linear), I just select `K=2` so that there is no increase in computational time for a training algorithm with asymptotic complexity linear in the number of training instances.

Answer (score -7):

#### Solution:

```
K = N/N*0.30
```

- N = Size of data set
- K = Fold

Comment: We can also choose 20% instead of 30%, depending on size you want to choose as your test set.

#### Example:

If data set size: N=1500; K=1500/1500*0.30 = 3.33; We can choose K value as 3 or 4

#### Note:

Large K value in leave one out cross-validation would result in over-fitting. Small K value in leave one out cross-validation would result in under-fitting.

Approach might be naive, but would be still better than choosing k=10 for data set of different sizes.

Comment: (-1) $\frac{N}{N \cdot 0.3} = \frac{1}{0.3} \approx 3.33 = const.$ so you are suggesting *always* to use k = 3 or 4 regardless of sample size - this is IMHO not substantially different from using k = 10 equally regardless of sample size.

Comment: K=N/N*0.3=10/3 which is a constant. So it is not logical to use that value for every condition.

Comment: This is, quite literally, one of the dumbest answers I have ever seen on this forum