# Cross validation with Test_size = 1% of the whole dataset; am I violating any machine learning rule?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a dataset of 21 classes with 90 samples per class. Each sample is 30s.
I want to know what is the minimum number of samples required for the testing (this is for biometrics, so the lower the # of samples the better).

I have done a StratifiedShufflesplit (10x10 fold) with 1 and 9 samples per class for the testing. The accuracies I got are:

- 9 samples: 89.21%
- 1 samples: 89.38%

But I know Andrew Ng recommends to divide data in 80%-20% (training, testing).

- With 9 samples, I have 90%-10%
- With 1 sample, I have 99%-1%

Answer (score 1):

As you report accuracy, I assume you're talking about classification. Also, the question in the 1st paragraph and the following description do not seem to be the same question to me.

Anyways, accuracy is the *fraction* of correct classified cases among the tested cases. Such proportions can be described by a binomial distribution, and the random uncertainty of the test result roughly depends on the absolute number of tested cases.

Cross validation procedures test *all* cases in turn, so there is [not much difference with varying size of the splits](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27730/choice-of-k-in-k-fold-cross-validation).

If you have 90 independent (!) cases in each class, then the class-wise accuracies (sensitivities) are tested with 90 cases each after the **cross validation** is finished.
Binomial 95% confidence interval for 89% of 90 cases yields about 81 - 94 % (you see that there is no point in reporting further digits here!)

Things look different if you go into **one-time splitting** (the typical setup for train - test aka hold out splits - as opposed to resampling techniques such as various flavors of cross validation or out-of-bootstrap validation). For one time splits, only a fraction of the available cases is ever tested. So splitting your 90 cases 80:20 would yield 18 test cases with a corresponding binomial 95% confidence interval for a proportion with 89% point estimate of maybe 66 - 98% (which is typically useless for practical purposes).