# Does each fold in a cross validation produce a new model that is only tested once?

Tags: cross-validation

My understanding of cross validation is that we create n partitions of the data, train on n-1, then test on 1. You go through n permutations. This means that we have n models, each tested once. So summing up the error is really more about evaluating the algorithm, or model parameters (e.g. how many trees in a gradient boosting machine). So for instance, I could do a run with 1k tree, and do a run with 5k trees, and even though the models are different each fold/validation, it should give me a better sense of whether 1k trees or 5k trees is better.

However, since each model is tested once, it doesn't really give me a better testing of an individual model. Is this a concern? Are there other ways to do that?  Am I missing something?

Comment: +1. Cross-validation is `about evaluating the algorithm`, that is exactly correct. As @DikranMarsupial likes to say, "[It is best to think of cross-validation as a way of estimating the generalisation performance of models generated by a particular procedure, rather than of the model itself](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27456/28666)".

Comment: In fact, your question can be considered a duplicate of that one. I suggest you read Dikran's answer there and if something remains unclear, edit your question to specify the remaining concern.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out Dikran's response. Don't think I can up vote a comment. I guess the only remaining question would be if I could get a reference to evaluation techniques that are more about thoroughly evaluating a single model to protect against (or at least measure) overfitting. Just trying to make sure I'm not missing something. I imagine repeated sampling, leave one out, repeated cv, etc.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "single model"?

Comment: See also a more detailed Dikran's answer in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602.