# Can I use the Grid-search CV best average performance as a metric?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm using a Grid Search CV to find optimal hyperparameters for an SVM.
I want to use the best combination of hyperparameters and evaluate model performance using those hyperparameters. Can I just use the average accuracy given by the Grid Search CV as a metric for model performance?

I've looked at [SE Post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-on-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation) as well as [SKLearn link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), which indicates that the performance may be biased. However, why would the performance be biased? Isn't the performance metric given by the cross-validation for unseen data (namely, the held-out set in the cross-validation)? And as this unseen data is different for each fold, as well as the trained model, wouldn't the metric given back by the cross-validation be a good representation of how it would perform on unseen data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you *look* at the CV results and *choose* a set of hyperparameters (into which all data involved in the CV in any fold enters), any data involved in that CV is not *unseen* any more to the final model.